# Blazor [Parameter] one way binding

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am passing an object from parent component to a child one.
The child one is expecting the parameter like so

`[Parameter] public Domain.Session.Session Item { get; set; }`

The child component then manipulates data in `Item` and returns it back to the parent component but only on user action like a button click.
If it seems like a strange thing to do consider that the child component is usually in a popup. So I have different child components that modify different aspects of `Item` and then return the modified object back the parent through a callback function. The issue is that if some data is modified but the popup is closed/cancelled the modification made to `Item` sticks because of the two way binding.

My questions is how can I pass a parameter to a child component in a one-way binding type of fashion.

Comment: This is not two way binding.  You are passing a reference to an object to the child, not the object.  You are modifying the same object.  If you want to pass a new object to the child you need to create one.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought too. So my only option manually creating a copy of the object before manipulating it? There isn't anything built in the Blazor can do fo me here?

Comment: No.  Personally I use records extensively.  They are easy to copy, and then create Edit classes when I need to mutate them.

Comment: Thank you. I have heard of Records before but my app is big enough now that I don't have a clear way to incorprorate and play around with what sounds like kind of a paradigm change. Is there some smaller hello world type example that deals with Records and going from immutable to edit classes in a way that we are disussing that you can point me to?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a copy of your object, or it will be destroyed by anything bound to it.  One common method is to use the JSON library to `Serialize` and then `Deserialize` your object.  Use the deserialized object in your EditForm, and on `Submit`you can return it in an `EventCallback<Domain.Session.Session>`, and then replace the original child in an event handler of the parent component.  Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to

Comment: Yes it is a bit of a paradigm shift.  See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I just create another "Item_temp" for Modal component, you could try this: 
Modal1.razor

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: block;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5>Modal title</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Modify "Item" :</p>
                <input @bind-value="Item_temp"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="SaveChange">Save changes</button>
                <button type="button" @onclick="CloseModal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public bool showModal { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> showModalChanged { get; set; }

    private void CloseModal()
    {
        showModalChanged.InvokeAsync(false);
    }


    [Parameter] public string Item { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ItemChanged { get; set; }
    private void SaveChange()
    {
        ItemChanged.InvokeAsync(Item_temp);
        showModalChanged.InvokeAsync(false);
    }

    public string Item_temp { get; set; }
}
```

Home.razor

```
@page "/"

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => { showModal = true; })">Show Modal</button>
@if (showModal)
{
    <Modal1 @bind-showModal="showModal" @bind-Item="Item"></Modal1>
}
<hr />
Item = @Item

@code {
    bool showModal = false;
    public string Item { get; set; } = "initial value";
}
```

Only update when you click "save changes"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example using a record `WeatherForecast`.  Using records in your data pipeline ensures you can't accidentally mutate them.

```cs
public record WeatherForecast
{
    public Guid WeatherUid { get; init; }
    public DateOnly Date { get; init; }
    public int TemperatureC { get; init; }
    public string? Summary { get; init; }
    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
}
```

Create a `WeatherForecastMutationContext`:

```cs
public class WeatherForecastMutationContext
{
    private WeatherForecast _originalRecord = new();
    public Guid WeatherUid => _originalRecord.WeatherUid;
    public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
    public string? Summary { get; set; }
    public bool IsDirty => _originalRecord != AsRecord;

    public WeatherForecastMutationContext(WeatherForecast record)
        => this.Load(record);

    public WeatherForecast AsRecord =>
        _originalRecord with
        {
            Date = this.Date,
            Summary = this.Summary,
            TemperatureC = this.TemperatureC,
        };

    private void Load(WeatherForecast record)
    {
        _originalRecord = record;
        Date = record.Date;
        Summary = record.Summary;
        TemperatureC = record.TemperatureC;
    }
}
```

This is the model for the `EditContext`. It's simple to track edit state.  You can add data validation to this if you wish.

When you want to save, you commit the new mutated record you get from the mutation context to the data pipeline to persist the data in the data store.